# What is the proper way to create a numpy array of transformation matrices

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, matrix

Given a list of rotation angles (lets say about the X axis):

```
import numpy as np
x_axis_rotations = np.radians([0,10,32,44,165])
```

I can create an array of matrices matching these angles by doing so:

```
matrices = []
for angle in x_axis_rotations:
    matrices.append(np.asarray([[1 , 0 , 0],[0, np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle)], [0, np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle)]]))
matrices = np.array(matrices)
```

This will work but it doesn't take advantage of numpy's strengths for dealing with large arrays... So if my array of angles is in the millions, doing it this way won't be very fast.

Is there a better (faster) way to do create an array of transform matrices from an array of inputs?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want a 3D array? Where is the input coming from? A file or something you generate at run time?

Comment: Could you explain the reason why you want to store that matrices rather than computing them when used?

Comment: @Simpom i want to implement the a point to triangle technique outlined in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.479.8237&rep=rep1&type=pdf). The idea is that by precomputing a transform matrix for each triangle of a mesh it becomes possible to reduce a 3D distance from points to triangles problem into a simpler 2D one which can be calculated faster than by doing a barycentric calculation. If all i want is to a single point query, then yeah there's no need to compute matrices. But if i have a million points to query then this should prove useful.

Comment: @ventsyv i want to create an array of 4x4 matrices. Read the comment i just l wrote to Simpom for the particular use case i want to this for. Input is coming from an external program in the form of an array of vertex positions describing a mesh of triangles, and an array of 3d points to query the closest point on the mesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a direct and simple approach:

```
c = np.cos(x_axis_rotations)
s = np.sin(x_axis_rotations)
matrices = np.zeros((len(x_axis_rotations), 3, 3))
matrices[:, 0, 0] =  1
matrices[:, 1, 1] =  c
matrices[:, 1, 2] = -s
matrices[:, 2, 1] =  s
matrices[:, 2, 2] =  c
```

---

timings, for the curious:

```
In [30]: angles = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(1000)

In [31]: timeit OP(angles)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.46 ms per loop

In [32]: timeit askewchan(angles)
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.6 µs per loop

In [33]: timeit divakar(angles)
10000 loops, best of 3: 93.8 µs per loop

In [34]: timeit divakar_oneline(angles)
10000 loops, best of 3: 56.1 µs per loop

In [35]: timeit divakar_combine(angles)
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.9 µs per loop
```

All are much faster than your loop, so use whichever you like the most :)

Comment: Nice and concise! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`linear indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing) to help out, like so -

```
# Get cosine and sine values in one-go
cosv = np.cos(x_axis_rotations)
sinv = np.sin(x_axis_rotations)

# Get size parameter
N = x_axis_rotations.size

# Initialize output array
out = np.zeros((N,3,3))

# Set the first element in each 3D slice as 1
out[:,0,0] = 1

# Calculate the first of positions where cosine valued elements are to be put
idx1 = 4 + 9*np.arange(N)[:,None]

# One by one put those 4 values in 2x2 blocks across all 3D slices
out.ravel()[idx1] = cosv
out.ravel()[idx1+1] = -sinv

out.ravel()[idx1+3] = sinv
out.ravel()[idx1+4] = cosv
```

Alternatively, you can set the elements in one-go after you have initialized the output array with `zeros` and set the first element in each slice as `1`, like so -

```
out.reshape(N,-1)[:,[4,5,7,8]] = np.column_stack((cosv,-sinv,sinv,cosv))
```

Between the above mentioned two approaches, two more *middleground* approaches could evolve, again put right after initializing with zeros and setting the first element in each 3D slice as `1`, like so -

```
out.reshape(N,-1)[:,[4,8]] = cosv[:,None]
out.reshape(N,-1)[:,[5,7]] = np.column_stack((-sinv[:,None],sinv[:,None]))
```

The last one would be -

```
out.reshape(N,-1)[:,[4,8]] = cosv[:,None]
out.reshape(N,-1)[:,5] = -sinv
out.reshape(N,-1)[:,7] = sinv
```

Comment: I like the elegance of these answers, but I think the indexing ends up just slowing it down.

Comment: @askewchan Well, I am scared about the column_stacks as they are known to be slow. It would be nice I guess to time all of these.

Comment: Your last solution shouldn't have the new axes for the last two lines, since the slice on the LHS only has one dimension.

Comment: @askewchan Thanks, that's right indeed, edited. I got the same runtime results as yours.

Comment: @Divakar thanks for this! I'll take askewchan's answer purely for how concise it is, but yours was close second!

Comment: @Fnord Good choice, the runtimes support that as well.